# Sequelize association, one to many, how to retrieve the one when querying the many table?

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

My associations are

```
Member.hasMany(models.Event);
Event.belongsTo(models.Member);
```

I need my query on Event model to retrieve the member data associated with the event.

```
models.Event.findAll() // I need Member associated with each Event.
```

Kind of like retrieving master when I query detail table

Answer (score 0):

Need to do this

```
    Event.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: Member
        }]
    })
```

Read Docs : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/

Comment: It won't let me do that. I can do     Model.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: models.Event
        }]
    })